# convergence of series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{n})}{\ln(n)}$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I am unable to test convergence for $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{n})}{\ln(n)}\;,\; \sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{n})}{\ln^2(n)}$$
I know from wolfram that the first diverges and second converges, both it said from comparison tests.

I was able to find that for cos instead of sin the second series diverges using the fact that for sufficiently large $n$'s, $n > \ln^2(n)$, and then using comparison test. But for $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{n})}{\ln(n)}$$ the series $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{n})}{n}$$ converges, which ruins the test. And I can't find something to substitute ln for, or sin for that matter. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Use the fact that $$\frac{1}{2n} \le \sin (1/n) \le \frac{1}{n}$$ and then the integral test on $\sum_{n} \frac{1}{n \log n}$ and $\sum_{n} \frac{1}{n \log^2 n}$.

Comment: Since $$0\le\dfrac{\sin\frac1n}{\ln^k n}\searrow 0$$ you can use Cauchy condensation test, coupled with $$\lim_{n\to\infty}2^n\sin(2^{-n})=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$$

Comment: Thanks! didn't think of Cauchy. That worked great.